A strong connectivity concept in directed hypergraphs
I am considering a finite directed hypergraph $H=(V,A)$, where each arc $a\in A$ is of the form $a=(S,T)$ with $S\cap T = \emptyset$.
I am interested in a particular notion of connectivity on $H$. In particular, I first pick some set $X\subseteq V$, and recursively update it with $X' = X \cup T$ if there exists some arc $(S,T)\in A$ such that $S\subseteq T$, e.g. all the source nodes $S$ are contained in $X$.Let us call the set generated in this manner $C(X)$.
Note that under the above operation, one can 'split up' arcs $a=(S,T)$ into multiple arcs $a_i=(S,t_i)$ where $T= \{t_1,\dots,t_n\}$.
I am wondering if this concept, or even just the 'strict' sense of connectivity based on a set as I defined it above is known in the literature. I tried looking around using the terms connectivity and transitive closure, but I can only find concepts in literature that consider connectivity where only require a single arc in the source node is necessary. I am not super familiar with hypergraph literature.
